# rss feeds in nutch

Tags: nutch

Actually i ma newbie to nutch. i want to khnow is there any way we crawl a rss feed then customize the parse data so that index can hv different fields from rss.
like
Suppose the rss feed hav a field source in item. i want to index this field..

thanxx
vibs

Answer (score 0):

You can find many [nutch experts here](http://lucene.apache.org/nutch/mailing_lists.html)

Answer (score 0):

Nutch has a plugin for parsing that kind of data. You have only two things to do: Active that plugin in your nutch-site.xml file config adding the plugin "feed". This make the pareser necesary for updating the solr index with metadata related feeds.